# Resolving shadowing of local scope with class scope

Tags: c++, scope

The scope resolution operator can be used to resolve name clashes between a class scope and the global scope (as shown in the initialization of `G::sum` below). Is it possible to resolve similar clashes between a local class' scope and its surrounding local scope (as (not) shown in the initialization of `L::sum` below)?

```
#include <cassert>

int clash_g = -332;

struct G {
  int clash_g = 333;
  int sum = clash_g + ::clash_g;
};

int main() {

  int clash_l = -332;

  struct L {
    int clash_l = 333;
    int sum = clash_l + clash_l;
  };

  assert(G().sum == 1);
  assert(L().sum == 666); // Want 1, like in G::sum

}
```

Comment: `L`'s function `fn` cannot access any `auto`-variables in `main`: Function-nesting (aside from Lambdas) is not a C++ feature: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0208466f77cf2d3f

Comment: @Deduplicator Of course. Sorry. Edited question to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all clash_l will be -332 not 333 
The answer is that you cannot resolve such a clash because a struct is a **datatype declaration** 
and the main is a function with **local scope** not global scope
so you can't address a variable in the main function from this struct **even if they have different names**

Edit:
you still can't access the "surrounding local scope" as you ask
because you're in a struct definition which is a new datatype definition
the work around is to declare a static variable in the main

```
static int x = -332
```

and call it normally in the struct

```
int sum = clash_l + x;
```

Comment: Yes , the use of static can solve the problem, you don't have to use a pointer , just static is enough

Comment: @AhmedFahmy question has been edited since your answer was posted now